# Trying to strech an image view so it takes up an entire screen

Tags: android, imageview

I have gotten the image to fill most of the screen, but for some reason it is not covering 1/2 an inch of white space on the bottom. I have played around with padding bottom and that did not help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:paddingLeft="-130dp"
    android:paddingRight="-330dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:scrollX="150dp"
    android:scrollY="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/jobs" />
```

Comment: Along with @Sishin's response, can you post the layout of the parent also?

Comment: Does the image you are displaying have an empty space at the bottom?

Comment: you are probably nesting this image within a layout that has some paddings/margins

Comment: remove the "adjust view bounds" parameter, then if it doesnt work out, remove the paddings as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use "android:background" instead of "android:src"

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Peru"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/traffic2" />

</LinearLayout>
```